# corrupted performance counters?

Tags: c#, .net, performancecounter

Performance counters are EVIL. Don't use them.

```
if(PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("ILoveYou")  ) // is true
{
    PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete("ILoveYou"); 
    //throws exception The **configuration registry** key is invalid
}
```

---

```
at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.RegisterFiles(String arg0, Boolean unregister)
at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.UnregisterCategory(String categoryName)
at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete(String categoryName)
at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.SetupCategory()
```

All I found is this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oanapl/archive/2009/04/24/fix-corrupted-performance-counters.aspx
(Using LODCTR /R)

and it doesn't help. As I have no idea what file are they talking about. Anyone got any other ideas?

PS
I use Windows XP SP3 may this be the problem? I understand it is suppose to support performance counters fully unless I cancel the page file.

**to make this clear my problemis that I'm unable to UNINSTALL my counters.**

Comment: In the link you gave there is another [link](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=300956). Have you followed these steps and still it doesn't work?

Comment: @Schaliasos I did follow the link but i failed to understand whta to do in code, I CAN theoreticly to impliment their instructions in code but thats complex long and very ugly.

Comment: now i realised that i failed to follow the links instructions the command requires somekind of file, I have no idea what kind. and cannot find explanation

Comment: Which file are you having trouble with? The ones in %systemroot% (C:\Windows, most likely) or the ones on your installation discs which you have to expand with the `expand` command from the command prompt?

Comment: What code is running the code you are showing us? Are you running multiple threads as the code above is not thread-safe (another thread can interrupt between the `if` check and the `Delete` call.

Comment: Thats all the code inside the main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My company runs into problems with the performance counters getting corrupt regularly.  If it is a problem with the actual counters being corrupt, you can check for corrupted Performance Counters by:

1. Going to `start | run | perfmon`
2. Click OK
3. Click on the add button on the toolbar in the right panel ("+" sign button)
4. Ensure that the proformance object drop down menu contains items and not just numbers

If the Counters are numbers or Blank:

Locate and Rename these 3 files in `%windir%\system32`:

- `Perfc009.dat`
- `Perfh009.dat`
- `Perfi009.dat`

Insert the Windows XP Install CD

Browse to their CD drive and into the I386 Folder (i.e. `D:\I386`)

Locate those same files here

Copy and Paste them from the CD back into System32

Reboot the computer.

This is the best solution we have found for the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a similar machine you can run lodctr /S:mycounters.ini to export all counters to 'mycounters.ini' and then import them on a broken machine with lodctr /R:mycounters.ini.  Keep in mind though, I've only used this procedure on two machines that I knew were almost identical in terms of perf counters.  I do not know if there would be issues with machines that do not match.

Comment: I've done it on the same machine with issues: backed up, manually edited backup text file (actually removed several counters), and than restored result file. And it worked.

Answer (score 3):

For me,

it was sufficient to re-create all performance counters with

```
lodctr /R
```

from a command-line with administrative rights (according to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956/en-us), but skipping the manual recreation of the base performance counters)

When checking the list of performance counters in the registry in

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009
```

it turned out that the content of that key startet with *lots* of whitespace. There was a list of performance counters with high counter indices at the very end of that key. After calling the command above, the key correctly contained the base performance counters as well (and did not contain the leading whitespace any more).

Answer (score 1):

Performance counters favor speed over usability and correctness. The performance counters in XP and later Windows versions can easily be broken. It is e.g. a very bad practice to create a new performance counter category on startup of your app and delete it on shutdown. Constant change to the performance counter categories is a sure receipe of getting corrupt performance counters.

I would create the categories only when it does not yet exist and leave it there until your app is uninstalled. Under what circumtances do you want to delete a performance counter category? The basic answer I can give to you is to not delete performance counter categories unless you need to.

A good link how to recreate performance counters via lodctr or EXCTRLST is from [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/knowledgebase/ANTS_Performance_Profiler/KB200810000316). You can download it [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000platform/exctrlst/1.00.0.1/nt5/en-us/exctrlst_setup.exe).

**Edit1**

First you need to find a tool that does fix your issue. [Exctrlst](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737958.aspx) gives you a UI to re enable corrupt preformance counters.

If that does work you can now check with procmon which registry keys are written during the repair operation and use this as input for your autorepair feature.

Comment: that IS my reinstaller. thats extacly my probelm.