# Can't get nservicebus performance counters to work in development/self host on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: nservicebus, performancecounter

Get this exception when running nservicebus.host.exe self-hosting either through Visual Studio or from command prompt. (Have tried both running from command prompt as administrator and my regular user):

> 2013-09-12 11:16:33,978 [1] FATAL NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost [(null)] <(nul
>   l)> - System.InvalidOperationException: NServiceBus performance counter for Crit
>   ical Time not set up correctly. Please run the NServiceBus infrastructure instal
>   lers to rectify this problem. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not R
>   ead Category Index: 9340.

I've tried running the "RunMeFirst.bat" which seems to run fine:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\NServiceBus\v3.3.4>runmefirst
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NServiceBus\v3.3.4>echo off
>          1 file(s) copied.
>          1 file(s) copied.
>          1 file(s) copied.
>          1 file(s) copied.
>
> Running infrastructure installers and exiting (ignoring other command line parameters if exist).
>   There is already a RavenDB service installed on this computer, current status:Running
>   Starting installation of PerformanceCounters
>   Installation of PerformanceCounters successful.
>   Checking if MSMQ is installed.
>   MSMQ is installed.
>   Checking that only needed components are active.
>   Installation is good.
>   Checking if DTC is configured correctly.

The machine is a windows server 2008 R2 with terminal services which is a shared development server for multiple devs. I suspect the stricter security on win server is to blame here since it works on my win 7 machine.

**EDIT**
Tried running "Install-PerformanceCounters" in Package Manager Console, but same problem. FYI, the output of Package Manager Console was (my command at the bottom):

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 2.2.40116.9051

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

Type 'get-help about_NServiceBus' to see all available NServiceBus commands. 
What if: Performing operation "Install-PerformanceCounters" on Target "DEV01". 
Performance Counters is setup and ready for use with NServiceBus 
What if: Performing operation "Install-Msmq" on Target "DEV01". 
Msmq is installed and setup for use with NServiceBus What if: 
Performing operation "Install-Dtc" on Target "DEV01". 
DTC is not properly configured 
What if: Performing operation "Install-RavenDB" on Target "DEV01".

PM> Install-PerformanceCounters 
True
PM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the powershell cmdlets, see http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/management-using-powershell

Comment: Tried this as well, but no luck. I updated my question with the PMC output.

Comment: Sometimes the performance counters get corrupted, you may need to reset them, google about it.

Comment: Looks like your link no longer exists @John.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by John Simons I found the answer in this SO question: [corrupted performance counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779699/corrupted-performance-counters)

In my particular case, running

```
lodctr /R
```

in admin command prompt was sufficient.